# Can't add text without append("g"), append("g") gives error from d3.js

Tags: d3.js, nodes, javascript

I am new to D3 and I am working with code from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795). I changed the code so I can add new nodes (neighbors) and edges to them with data from MySql upon click on a node, which is why part of the node code is in `start()`. I want to append text labels to the nodes, and from some googling I understand that both the circle element and the text element needs to be within a `g`. However, when I do this, I get an error from d3.js on line 742:

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node':
>   The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of
>   this node

Why is this and how do I fix it to get what I want, while preserving the addNode functionality?

Here is my code:

```
var width = 960,
   height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [],
    links = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(120)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")/*.append("g")*/,
    link = svg.selectAll(".link");

function start() {
    link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    link.exit().remove();

    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
    node.enter()/*.append("g")*/
        .append("circle")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; })
            .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
            .attr("r", 8)
        .on("click", nodeClick)
        .append("text")
            .text(function(d) {return d.id; });

    node.exit().remove();
    force.start();
}

function nodeClick() {
    var node_id = event.target.id;
    handleClick(node_id, "node");
}

function tick() {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
```

The commented-out `append("g")` indicates where I tried to place it (separate attempts).

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you getting the error?

Comment: in d3.js at line 742 (not my code). The line is:  `return this.insertBefore(name.apply(this, arguments), before.apply(this, arguments) || null);`

Comment: But something in your code is calling some d3 function that causes this error. What is that line in your code?

Comment: addEdge()->start()->d3.js
`function addEdge(node_1, node_2) {
    links.push({source: node_1, target: node_2});
    start();
   }`

Comment: The code, as you've posted it, works fine for me.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff do labels also appear for you?

Comment: No. There's no data in your code.

Comment: the text of the label is supposed to be the id of the node, thus the  `.append("text").text(function(d) {return d.id; });`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff and the ids are retrieved asynchronously outside the code in the Q. I know the data is received properly because I see the elements get the proper ID in the browser element inspector

Comment: My point is that it's not immediately obvious to me where the error comes from and I can't reproduce it with the information you've given.

Answer (score 2):

You want to cache the d3 selector before appending the text.

```
node.enter().append("g")
    .append("circle")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; })
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("r", 8)
    .on("click", nodeClick)
    .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.id; });
```

That'll work but create a xml structure like this:

```
<g>
    <circle>
        <text>...</text>
    </circle>
 </g>
```

What you want is:

```
<g>
    <circle>...</circle>
    <text>...</text>
 </g>
```

To achieve that, you must insert one step:

```
var g = node.enter().append("g");
g.append("circle")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; })
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("r", 8)
    .on("click", nodeClick);
g.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.id; });
```

Comment: I tried implementing your lowermost block of code, but I still get the same error. Perhaps it has to do with the `node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});`?